# Remove "/" in a bash variable directory

Tags: bash

I just wrote a script which waits for a path from the user. I use `read` for that.

To be more user-friendly you can use <kbd>tab</kbd> to complete the path if this one exists.

My problem is: if the file exists, the `"/"` string is added at the end of line. So I just want to delete it, I search here and on the Internet and I found this:

```
echo ${str::-1)
```

So I used it with a simple iteration (if found `"/"` at the end then delete) but it return to me: `"str is a directory..."` when I run the script as error message.

Here is an example:

```
read -e -p "Where do you want to install it ?
Install directory : " _installdir

echo "$_installdir"
_slashdel=echo "$_installdir" |tail -c 1
echo -e "$_slahdel" #just used for debug here
if [ "$_slahdel" = "/" ];
then
        echo "{echo _installdir::-1}"
fi
echo "install dir :" "$_installdir"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to strip an optional trailing `/`, it's better to use `${str%/}`:

```
read -e -p "Where do you want to install it ?
Install directory : " _installdir

_installdir=${_installdir%/}
echo "install dir : $_installdir"
```

Not only it's simpler, but if there is no trailing `/`, then it will simply keep the original value.
So you don't need an `if` statement like you used in your original script.

You can learn more about string manipulations in Bash here:

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

Btw, your script was full of errors. You can verify the sanity of your scripts on [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Most of the code is irrelevant (you're testing `_slahdel`, which is not the same as `_slashdel`).

The error message comes from this part (which you should've found yourself by minifying the code):

```
_slashdel=echo "$_installdir"
```

This tells bash to run the command `$_installdir` with the environment variable `_slashdel` set to `echo`. Because `$_installdir` is a directory, it can't be run, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
read -e -p "Where do you want to install it ?
Install directory : " _installdir

echo "$_installdir"
_slashdel=$(echo -n "$_installdir" |tail -c 1)
echo -n "$_slashdel" #just used for debug here
if [ "$_slashdel" = "/" ];
then
        _installdir="${_installdir::-1}"
fi
echo "install dir :" "$_installdir"
```